# How to keep data associated with MKAnnotation from being lost after a callout pops up and user taps disclosure button?

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkannotation

How do I keep data associated with an MKAnnotation object after the user taps the pin, sees a callout, and taps the disclosure button which opens a detailed view controller? I want to display all data associated with the pin in the detail view controller.

I have a simple MKAnnotation class that looks like:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface VoiceMemoryAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    NSString * blobkey;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * blobkey;

-(id)initWithBlobkey:(NSString *) key andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c;
@end
```

I implemented the call back "viewForAnnotation"

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id     <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView*singleAnnotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];


// PM: this pin will have a callout (i.e. dont' forget to override title function! Else exception thrown)
    singleAnnotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

// PM: add disclosure button
    UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

// PM: when user taps disclosure button, bring them to another page with details about the selected voice memory
       [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showPinDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    singleAnnotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

    return singleAnnotationView;
}
```

If I understand correctly, the above method is called when you add a VoiceMemoryAnnotation to a map object.  When this viewForAnnotation is called, I simply allocate a MKPinAnnotationView object and return it.  When the user taps this retuned pin, they see the callout.  As soon as they click the disclosure button it  calls "showPinDetails":

```
- (void)showPinDetails:(id)sender
{


    detailViewController = [[MemoryDetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MemoryDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

The problem is the "sender" object does not contain any information about which pin was selected.  Is there some way I can pass in the selected annotation to the showPinDetails method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the `showPinDetails:` method, you can get the currently selected annotation from the map view's `selectedAnnotations` property.

That property is an `NSArray` but since the map view only allows one annotation to be selected at a time, you would just use the object at index 0.  For example:

```
- (void)showPinDetails:(id)sender
{
    if (mapView.selectedAnnotations.count == 0)
    {
        //no annotation is currently selected
        return;
    }

    id<MKAnnotation> selectedAnn = [mapView.selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:0];

    if ([selectedAnn isKindOfClass[VoiceMemoryAnnotation class]])
    {
        VoiceMemoryAnnotation *vma = (VoiceMemoryAnnotation *)selectedAnn;
        NSLog(@"selected VMA = %@, blobkey=%@", vma, vma.blobkey);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"selected annotation (not a VMA) = %@", selectedAnn);
    }

    detailViewController = [[MemoryDetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MemoryDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Instead of using a custom button action method, it can be easier to use the map view's `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method which lets you get access to the selected annotation more directly.  In `viewForAnnotation`, remove the `addTarget` and just implement the delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
    calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    id<MKAnnotation> selectedAnn = view.annotation;

    if ([selectedAnn isKindOfClass[VoiceMemoryAnnotation class]])
    {
        VoiceMemoryAnnotation *vma = (VoiceMemoryAnnotation *)selectedAnn;
        NSLog(@"selected VMA = %@, blobkey=%@", vma, vma.blobkey);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"selected annotation (not a VMA) = %@", selectedAnn);
    }

    //do something with the selected annotation... 
}
```

Comment: Anna - This is awesome.  I implemented your idea of implementing the delegate method "calloutAccessoryControlTapped" and this worked perfectly.  I copied / pasted your code and it worked exactly like I wanted.