# How do I know which callout has been clicked?

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I'm having alot of trouble trying to identify which callout bubble has been clicked.

Is there a way of identifying the callout bubbles some how as I've tried a number of examples on here but because I'm quite new to Objective C I can't seem to work out how to use them.

The following answers I've been trying to use but I'm confused with them

[How to track which annotation callout clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080275/how-to-track-which-annotation-callout-clicked)

I'm looking at tagging the annotations but thats even confusing me. :(

Taken from the second answer in the above link:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]){
    return nil;

    if(annotation.tag == 111)
        //Do something
    else
        //Do some other thing
}
```

How does the first part of this snippet work, perhaps if I understood it better I'd know what I'm working with.

Also how would I go about retrieving the tags when the callout is clicked so I can make the app respond respectively.

Comment: See these examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565197/how-to-find-which-annotation-send-showdetails, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876042/annotation-details-after-detail-disclosure-pressed, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462699/how-to-recognize-which-pin-was-tapped, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812471/mkpinannotationview-different-actions-in-different-pins, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797047/how-to-keep-data-associated-with-mkannotation-from-being-lost-after-a-callout-po

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass MKPinAnnotationView so you can identify it when

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKPinAnnotationView *)view
```

is called.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create class which extends MKAnnotation and create some property like tag and assign unique value or tag and add in mapview like.

```
Place* home = [[Place alloc] init] ;
home.name = [dForMap valueForKey:@"shortaddress"];
home.latitude = [[dForMap valueForKey:@"latitude"]floatValue];
home.longitude = [[dForMap valueForKey:@"longitude"]floatValue];
home.description = [dForMap valueForKey:@"shortaddress"];
home.flierid = count;
PlaceMark* from = [[PlaceMark alloc] initWithPlace:home] ;
from.flierid = count;
from.mapAnnotationType = MapAnnotationTypeProperty;    
[self addAnnotation:from];
```

you can check the property in didSelectAnnotationView method like this way when callout bubble is clicked.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
PlaceMark *a = (PlaceMark*)view.annotation;
Place *test = a.place;
int tag = test.flierid;
}
```

Thanks.