# Pass Parse PFobject objectID to map annotation view button title

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have an annotation view setup that adds a UIButton to rightCalloutAccessoryView. What I am trying to do is set the title of the button to the objectID of the parse object that the annotation represents.

My current result is that every annotation is getting the objectID of the first object in the query. What am I doing wrong here?

Looking at the code below what I am finding is that restaurantID is not being set each time a pin drops on the map. It seems to me I have it in the correct place as the title and subtitle of the pins update correctly.

Here is what I have done:

1.) In my mainViewController.h I have declared a string to hold the objectID of the PFobject:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *restaurantID;
```

2.) In my mainViewController.m I have synthesized the variable

```
@synthesize restaurantID;
```

3.) In my PFquery I am setting this restaurantID to the objectID of the PFobject ( restaurantID = [object objectId];):

```
 for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            PFGeoPoint *point = [[object objectForKey:@"geoLocation"] init];

            CLLocationCoordinate2D spot;
            spot.latitude = point.latitude;
            spot.longitude = point.longitude;
            MKPointAnnotation *foodPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
            foodPoint.coordinate = (spot);
            restaurantID = [object objectId];
            foodPoint.title = [object objectForKey:@"restaurantName"];
            foodPoint.subtitle = [object objectForKey:@"cuisineType"];
            leftIcon = [object objectForKey:@"restaurantImage"];
            [leftIcon getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                    // image can now be set on a UIImageView
                }
            }];
            [self.mainMap addAnnotation:foodPoint];
        }
```

Then in my annotation view I set the title of the button to be the restaurantID:

```
UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[rightButton setTitle:restaurantID forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[rightButton addTarget:self
                action:@selector(buttonMethod:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

In my buttonMethod: I have an NSLog to display the title of the button pressed. The value remains the same as I click on different pins. It grabs the objectID of one Parse object, but it is not grabbing a new objectID for each object in the query.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `viewForAnnotation` delegate is *not* necessarily called immediately after you call `addAnnotation` *nor* is it necessarily called only once for each annotation.

The map view will call the delegate method when it wants to show the annotation.  This may happen a little later than when you add it or it could happen again for the same annotation if the user pans or zooms the map and the annotation comes onto the screen again.

Therefore, you cannot use the view-controller-level `restaurantID` variable the way you are (by assuming that it was just set in relation to the annotation the map view is calling `viewForAnnotation` for).  By the time the map view calls `viewForAnnotation`, `restaurantID` is set to some value that is unrelated to the annotation the map view is currently getting the view for.

Instead, you should put the `objectId` (or even the whole `object`) in each annotation *individually*.

Right now, since you're using the `MKPointAnnotation` class, the only properties you can set are `coordinate`, `title`, and `subtitle`.

**You need to subclass `MKPointAnnotation` or create your own custom class that implements the `MKAnnotation` protocol and add a `restaurantID` property to it.**

Set this property when adding the annotation:

```
CustomAnnotationClass *foodPoint = [[CustomAnnotationClass alloc] init];
foodPoint.coordinate = (spot);
foodPoint.restaurantID = [object objectId]; //<--put objectId in foodPoint
foodPoint.title = [object objectForKey:@"restaurantName"];
```

Then in `viewForAnnotation`, use the `annotation` parameter to get the values relevant to the annotation the map view is *currently* calling for:

```
//first make sure annotation is our custom type...
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomAnnotationClass class]])
{
    UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    //cast annotation parameter to our class so compiler understands...
    CustomAnnotationClass *fp = (CustomAnnotationClass *)annotation;

    //get restaurantID from the annotation parameter ("fp")...
    [rightButton setTitle:fp.restaurantID forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    ...
}
```

Also be sure to handle annotation view re-use properly.  That is, if `dequeue` returns a view, update its `annotation` property to the current one (eg. `annotationView.annotation = annotation;`).  If this is not done, it's again possible for the view or callout to show data for a different annotation.

That should resolve the issue with the button showing the wrong title.

**However**, I assume you're setting the button's title just so you can figure out which annotation the user tapped.  That will "work" but it's a bit kludgy since the title (restaurantID) will appear to the right of the disclosure icon (though it may not be visible in the callout).

Instead of that approach, I highly recommend using the map view's `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method or the map view's `selectedAnnotations` property.  See these questions for examples:

- [How to recognize which pin was tapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462699/how-to-recognize-which-pin-was-tapped)
- [How to keep data associated with MKAnnotation from being lost after a callout pops up and user taps disclosure button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797047/how-to-keep-data-associated-with-mkannotation-from-being-lost-after-a-callout-po)

This way, you can get a reference to the annotation object itself and from that get the restaurantID (same way as in `viewForAnnotation`).

Comment: HUGE HELP. Thank you! Subclassing MKPointAnnotation was clearly the way to go. I'll look at calloutAccessoryControlTapped delegate method next to make this a more professional implementation.

Comment: Anna- since you are so knowledgable on the MapKit, would you mind taking a look at this question? My subclass is working fine for the ID I am passing, but I can't get my UIImage to pass from my custom sublass: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875278/having-trouble-passing-uiimage-to-mkpinannotationview

Comment: How does one the loop through the mapView's annotations and retrieve that id again? They seem to become MKUserLocation objects when calling them from map.annotations :/

Comment: @ByronCoetsee: Use isKindOfClass to check what type of annotation each one is.  When you find your class, cast it to your class type and then retrieve your custom property.  If not the id you're looking for, move on to the next one.