# Having trouble passing UIImage to MKPinAnnotationView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, parse-platform, mkannotationview

I subclassed `MKPointAnnotation` and added a `NSString` and a `UIImage` so I can pass these elements to an `MKPinAnnotationView`. The string passes into the `MKPinAnnotationView` fine, but the image attribute is coming through as null. I can't figure out why. I will say that one time running this code on my phone the image appeared on a pin once, so maybe I have a memory leak? The other 1000 times I've compiled the images show as null in the log and do not appear. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my subclass customMapAnnotation.h:

```
@interface customMapAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *restaurantID;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *restaurantIcon;

@end
```

Here is where my `customMapAnnotation` is created. I'm using Parse.com so there is a statement here to convert a PFFile to a UIImage. If I check the log I confirm that `foodPoint.restaurantIcon` has a value when this is ran.

```
customMapAnnotation *foodPoint = [[customMapAnnotation alloc] init];
foodPoint.coordinate = spot;
foodPoint.restaurantID = [object objectId];
foodPoint.title = [object objectForKey:@"restaurantName"];
foodPoint.subtitle = [object objectForKey:@"cuisineType"];
leftIcon = [object objectForKey:@"restaurantImage"];

[leftIcon getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

        // image can now be set on a UIImageView
        foodPoint.restaurantIcon = image;
    }
}];

[self.mainMap addAnnotation:foodPoint];
```

Now here is all of my code for my `MKPinAnnotationView`. Notice I run an `NSLog` to confirm if `fp.restaurantIcon` has a value, and it is null. I know this use of `NSLog` is not graceful, but it should return the memory location of the image. It comes back null. Again, my other custom attribute `fp.restaurantId` is working fine.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    static NSString *identifier = @"RoutePinAnnotation";
    if (annotation == mapView.userLocation)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    else
    {
        MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                        initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        pinView.animatesDrop=NO;
        pinView.canShowCallout=YES;

        UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

        //cast annotation parameter to our class so compiler understands...
        customMapAnnotation *fp = (customMapAnnotation *)annotation;

        NSLog(fp.restaurantIcon);

        //get restaurantID from the annotation parameter ("fp")...
        [rightButton setTitle:fp.restaurantID forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [rightButton addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(buttonMethod:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

        //NSLog(fp.restaurantIcon);

        UIImageView *profileIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:fp.restaurantIcon];
        profileIconView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,31,31);

        pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = profileIconView;

        return pinView;
    }
}
```

Here is my `didSelectAnnotationView:`

```
 - (void) mainMap:(MKMapView *)mainMap didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[chwMapAnnotation class]])
    {
        chwMapAnnotation *fp = (chwMapAnnotation *)view.annotation;
        UIImageView *profileIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:fp.restaurantIcon];
        profileIconView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,31,31);
        view.leftCalloutAccessoryView = profileIconView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this may caused by your background image loader getDataInBackgroundWithBlock. You can set a break point in the UIImageView *profileIconView and check if the fp.restaurantIcon is nil. It could be that the restaurantIcon is still nil while you create MKPinAnnotationView.

Comment: Can you try this,

            UIImageView *profileIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 37, 31)];
            profileIconView.clipsToBounds = YES;
            profileIconView.image = fp.restaurantIcon;
            pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = profileIconView;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comment by @Vincent that since the images are being loaded in the background asynchronously, they have not yet been loaded when `viewForAnnotation` is called and so the annotation's callout is stuck with a blank left icon.

When the image loading is finished by `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock`, there is no automated signal telling the annotation view to refresh its `leftCalloutAccessoryView`.

A *crude* workaround in this case would be to manually force the refresh of the `leftCalloutAccessoryView` when the annotation is selected (which is when the callout will be displayed containing the `leftCalloutAccessoryView`).

When an annotation is selected, the map view calls the `didSelectAnnotationView` delegate method.  Here, the crude workaround can be applied:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[customMapAnnotation class]])
    {
        customMapAnnotation *fp = (customMapAnnotation *)view.annotation;
        UIImageView *profileIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:fp.restaurantIcon];
        profileIconView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,31,31);
        view.leftCalloutAccessoryView = profileIconView;
    }
}
```

Of course, it's possible that the image *still* hasn't loaded for the annotation that was selected (it's either just taking very long or the image url is invalid, etc).

What you can do is in `viewForAnnotation`, if `fp.restaurantIcon` is `nil`, set the left icon to some generic "loading" icon that you add to the project resources.  In `didSelectAnnotationView`, you can also first check if `fp.restaurantIcon` is still `nil` and, if so, do nothing (ie. leave the icon as the generic "loading" icon).

A less crude solution might be to create a custom annotation view class that listens for an "image finished loading" message from its associated annotation and refreshes itself automatically.

Comment: I tried the didSelectAnnotationView method, but it did not change anything. I don't think I'm having any trouble with image loading times or url because my tableViewControllers display the images without issue for the same objects. I added my code for the method to my question above.

Comment: Have you actually named your delegate method `mainMap:didSelectAnnotationView:`?  Naming it `mainMap:` won't work because the map view is looking specifically for `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:`.  With delegate methods, you can change the internal parameter names but not the visible method signature.

Comment: I was typing too fast there; you are completely right. I mistakenly entered my map object name in the delegate method. Surprised it didn't kick out an error. the didSelectAnnotation fixes the issue and images load promptly.

Answer (score 0):

I would say don't try to subclass MKPointAnnotation, create your own object that conforms to the MKAnnotation protocol, and use annotation views that are NOT MKPinAnnotationViews.